# Find text between two static strings

Tags: regex, vba, outlook

I parse message data into a CSV file via Outlook rules.

How can I take the example below and store the text under "Customer Log Update:" into a string variable?

> [Header Data]
>
> Description: Problem: A2 - MI ERROR - R8036
>
> Customer Log Update:
> I'm having trouble with order #458362.  I keep getting Error R8036, can you please assist?
>
> Thanks!
>
> View problem at http://...
> [Footer Data]

Desired result to be stored into the string variable (note that the result may contain newlines):

> I'm having trouble with order #458362.  I keep getting Error R8036, can you please assist?
>
> Thanks!

I haven't attempted to code anything pertaining to my question.

```
Function RegFind(RegInput, RegPattern)
Dim regEx As New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
Dim matches, s
regEx.Pattern = RegPattern
regEx.IgnoreCase = True
regEx.Global = False
s = ""
If regEx.Test(RegInput) Then
    Set matches = regEx.Execute(RegInput)
    For Each Match In matches
        s = Match.Value
    Next
    RegFind = s
Else
    RegFind = ""
End If
End Function

Sub CustomMailMessageRule(Item As Outlook.MailItem)

MsgBox "Mail message arrived: " & Item.Subject

Const FileWrite = file.csv `file destination

Dim FF1 As Integer
Dim subj As String
Dim bod As String

On Error GoTo erh

subj = Item.Subject
'this gets a 15 digit number from the subject line
subj = RegFind(subj, "\d{15}")

bod = Item.Body
'following line helps formatting, lots of double newlines in my source data
bod = Replace(bod, vbCrLf & vbCrLf, vbCrLf)

'WRITE FILE
FF1 = FreeFile
Open FileWrite For Append As #FF1
    Print #FF1, subj & "," & bod
Close #FF1

Exit Sub

erh:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, Err.Number

End Sub
```

Comment: Regex in VBA? What code have you written so far?

Comment: I used a regex pattern search just fine, but having trouble with this more complicated example.  The answer might not include regex, I don't know.

Comment: Please show us the code you have written so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not something simple like this:

```
Function GetCustomerLogUpdate(messageBody As String) As String
    Const sStart As String = "Customer Log Update:"
    Const sEnd As String = "View problem at"
    Dim iStart As Long
    Dim iEnd As Long

    iStart = InStr(messageBody, sStart) + Len(sStart)
    iEnd = InStr(messageBody, sEnd)

    GetCustomerLogUpdate = Mid(messageBody, iStart, iEnd - iStart)
End Function
```

I tested it using this code and it worked:

```
Dim messageBody As String
Dim result As String

messageBody = "Description: Problem: A2 - MI ERROR - R8036" & vbCrLf & _
    "Customer Log Update:" & vbCrLf & _
    "I 'm having trouble with order #458362.  I keep getting Error R8036, can you please assist?" & vbCrLf & _
    "Thanks!" & vbCrLf & _
    "View problem at http://..." 

result = GetCustomerLogUpdate(messageBody)

Debug.Print result
```

Answer (score 4):

While I would also go the more direct route like Jean-François Corbett did as the parsing is very simple, you could apply the Regexp approach as below

The pattern
`Update:([\S\s]+)view`
says match all characters between "Update" and "view" and return them as a submatch

This piece `[\S\s]` says match all non-whitespace or whitespace characters - ie everything.
In [vbscript](/questions/tagged/vbscript) a `.` matches everything **but** a newline, hence the need for the `[\S\s]` workaround for this application

The submatch is then extracted by 
`objRegM(0).submatches(0)`

```
Function ExtractText(strIn As String)
    Dim objRegex As Object
    Dim objRegM As Object
    Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With objRegex
        .ignorecase = True
        .Pattern = "Update:([\S\s]+)view"
        If .test(strIn) Then
            Set objRegM = .Execute(strIn)
            ExtractText = objRegM(0).submatches(0)
        Else
            ExtractText = "No match"
        End If
    End With
End Function

Sub JCFtest()

Dim messageBody As String
Dim result As String
messageBody = "Description: Problem: A2 - MI ERROR - R8036" & vbCrLf & _
              "Customer Log Update:" & _
              "I 'm having trouble with order #458362.  I keep getting Error R8036, can you please assist?" & vbCrLf & _
              "Thanks!" & vbCrLf & _
              "View problem at http://..."


MsgBox ExtractText(messageBody)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you!  Just verified this works as described.  This is the "exact" answer to my question, though like you said, the first answer is probably the best suggestion. +1